# Speed up RDS Postgres instance restart

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a production DB instance hosted on RDS Postges which needs a reboot. We are making changes to some static Postgres config params which require a reboot of the instance. This will bring our application (which is widely used) down for sometime. Is there a way to speed up RDS Postgres instance restart time so that it can come back up asap?

Comment: Is the instance multi-AZ? Outage periods during reboots of multi-AZ instance is typically a few seconds because of the way it does failover internally. Single-AZ instances take much longer. There isn't any way to speed up restarts beyond using multi-az AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, it is multi-AZ. Will the writes to the writer node be affected/stopped during the reboot time?

Comment: Yes, but for less than 1 minute from my experience.